# Setting a delay on a one-character string looped user input that uses a bufferedreader in java (cmd program)

Tags: java, delay, bufferedreader

I'm writing a program that is a basic 2D command window game, that uses a bufferedreader with the .readline() method to get a WASD input to determine what direction the "Character" (asterisk) will move. However, if the player does nothing, I need the program to keep going and just keep the character in place. This all happens in a loop that goes roughly like

1. determine player movement needed
2. determine other needed changes to the board
3. change the board
4. rinse and repeat.

with the loop getting stopped at step 1 any time the user decides to not move.
 I have read several other posts, and most of them seem to relate to client-server connections, which does not apply here. Another post I found seemed to have an answer, but as the context of the code was different and I did not understand the code due to my sparse experience programming, I can not make enough sense of it to use it.

[Set timeout on user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49592555/set-timeout-on-user-input)

I am unfamiliar with what a "Future" and "Executor" do, although I have seen the term executor thrown around a lot in other code, so if someone could even just explain those two things in relation to the problem, that would be great! I apologize that I don't have any source code to post with this question, but I really have no clue where to start on this one other than to create a BufferedReader, which is fairly irrelevant.

Edit: to add a bit more information, I plan to take the output of the br.readline every half second or so and then update then update the board even if nothing has been entered. I think the first step to get this done is creating some kind of input stream, possibly other than a bufferedreader, that does not require the user to press enter every time they want to move or not move, so maybe that would be a better place to start.

Comment: `Executor` and `Future` are used in multi-threaded (concurrency) programming.`Executor` is a high-level API that helps in thread management. `Future` represents something, usually some kind of task or action, where it is expected to run concurrently in another thread, and that your main thread can expect to get a result later on.

Comment: One way to understand any kind of code is to refer to the documentation on how a particular class is used

Comment: Ok, so the                                                        Future future = executor.submit(task);
        try {
            String input = (String)future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            System.out.println(input);
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            future.cancel(true);
            System.out.println("Sorry you run out of time!");
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        } finally {
            executor.shutdownNow();
        }
 is run in parallel with the line of code before it that contains br?

Comment: @Jai is there any kind of code I need to type in advance that signals the program to look ahead for the parallel code, or is that what the executor is for?